# "RTNETLINK answer: File exists" renew ip

Tags: networking, dhcp

I want to scrape website with my pi but first id like to know how to ask for a new ip in case i get ban. I tried with:

```
$ sudo dhclient -r
>>>Killed old client process
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
>>>[ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
$ sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
$ sudo dhclient
>>>RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want. What is the question? How to get a new ip address? If using DHCP you will always get the same ip address if available. That is by design. You are mixing some old networking commands without respect the default network environment and where I can't see for what that should be good.

Comment: As long as you have the same MAC adr. the DHCP server will try to give you the same IP adr.

Comment: i want to change my public ip address so i get unban but looking what you wrote seems an impossible thing as long as i got the same MAC